# use .oleobjects.textbox.text in if statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have a textbox and an png image on my worksheet (not in userform). The png image loads the calendar and the value selected on calendar is returned to the textbox.

I further want to use the .oleobject in a if loop.
Like if some xyz variable >= .oleobject

Below is the code for reference.

```
Sub futurejoiners()
Dim lr As Long

Windows("EMPDATA.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("INPUTDATA").Select

lr = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For i = 2 To lr
Windows("EMPDATA.xlsm").Activate
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("TextBox2").Object.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please select the reporting start and end dates in Sheet1"
    Exit Sub
Else
    If Cells(i, "J").value >= ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("TextBox2").Object.Text Then
    Cells(i, "J").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End If
Next
End Sub
```

I get a runtime error 1004 unable to get the oleobjects property of the worksheet class on the if statement where it checks for = ""

I strongly believe something wrong in the way im calling the workbook or worksheet of that oleobject.

Please help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Ok it worked by removing the Thisworkbook..  using If Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("TextBox2").Object.Text = "" Then does not give any error but later at Selection.EntireRow.Delete it doesnot delete the records. :(

Comment: The syntax seems correct.  So if the workbook running the code has a sheet named "Sheet1", and the sheet contains an ActiveX textbox named "TextBox2", it should work.  Or is the textbox actually a Form control?

Comment: Hi Domenic, Thanks for the reply. My workbook has a sheet named as "Sheet1" & also contains an ActiveX textbox named "TextBox2" (i can say that with 100% surety as the calendar i have is fetching the values to that textbox2) .  In my above comment i have removed thisworksheet and it has stopped getting errors its just running through. The second if condition where it has to delete rows - its not deleting the rows

Comment: What is Cells(i, "J") 's  parant workbook.  And what is ThisWorkbook ?

Comment: What I'm trying is - I've a list of employees in INPUTDATA but it has emps. who would be joining the organisation in future. For ex. month is Sept, it will be 01-Sept to 30-Sept & emps joining in Oct or later should be deleted. Now the start date and end date is selected in a activex textbox using a calendar in sheet1 of workbook "EMPDATA.xlsm" which has the list of emps. And in the macro i have activated that workbook too. Cell(i,"J") are the cells where there is joining date entered in "EMPDATA.xlsm". I have removed ThisWorkbook from my code and now its running through without deleting data

Comment: In VBA ,  ThisWorkbook  means the book of having code.

Comment: For i = 2 To lr    to be   For i = lr To 2  step -1

Comment: and check  OLEObjects("TextBox2").Object.Text  is string or datevalue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it works well. But it is desirable to unusing select, activate method.

```
Sub futurejoiners()
Dim lr As Long
Dim myWS  As Worksheet
Dim myWB As Workbook
Dim myDate
Dim i As Long

Set myWB = worboooks("EMPDATA.xlsm")
Set myWS = myWB.Sheets("INPUTDATA")
'Windows("EMPDATA.xlsm").Activate
'Sheets("INPUTDATA").Select
With myWS
    lr = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For i = lr To 2 Step -1 '<~~ large to small step -1
        'Windows("EMPDATA.xlsm").Activate
        myDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("TextBox2").Object.Text

        If myDate = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please select the reporting start and end dates in Sheet1"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            If IsNumeric(myDate) Then
            Else
                myDate = DateValue(myDate)
            End If
            'If .Cells(i, "J").Value >= ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("TextBox2").Object.Text Then
            If .Cells(i, "J").Value >= myDate Then
                Cells(i, "J").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Dy.Lee. It works :)  Others - if referring to above code change to set myWB = workbooks("EMPDATA.xlsm:) & myDate = myWB.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("TextBox2").object.Text